# Unable to select a dropdown which is hidden

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to select a values from dropdown in Selenium Webdriver. But every time I end up  with an error in console

This is my site [URL](https://www.o2.co.uk/shop/smartwatches/samsung/gear-s2/#contractType=nonconnected) and below is the snap of element :

[image]

I've tried with the below code but its not working

```
Select dropdown= new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@on-dimension-select = 'selectQuantityDimension']/*[@role='combobox']")));
dropdown.selectByValue("4");
```

Getting the below exception : -

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element
>    should have been "select" but was "span" Build info: version:
>   'unknown', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:43:45 -0700'

Also tried this way too :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@on-dimension-select = 'selectQuantityDimension']/*[@role='combobox']")).click();
Select dropdown= new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@on-dimension-select = 'selectQuantityDimension']/select/")));
dropdown.selectByValue("4");
```

And this time error is :

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable
>   to locate an element with the xpath expression
>   //div[@on-dimension-select = 'selectQuantityDimension']/select/
>   because of the following error: SyntaxError: Failed to execute
>   'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//div[@on-dimension-select =
>   'selectQuantityDimension']/select/' is not a valid XPath expression.

This is the HTML code for the same :

```
 <div class="ng-isolate-scope ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-show="!docked" ng-model="variantOptionsModel" on-dimension-select="selectQuantityDimension" docked="docked">
  <label>Quantity:</label>
    <select class="accessory-option ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-model="model.selectedQuantity" ng-options="quantity for quantity in model.quantityDropDownValues track by quantity" ng-change="quantityClick()" data-qa-quantity-value="" style="display: none;">
     <option value="1" selected="selected" label="1">1</option>
     <option value="2" label="2">2</option>
     <option value="3" label="3">3</option>
     <option value="4" label="4">4</option>
     <option value="5" label="5">5</option>
     <option value="6" label="6">6</option>
   </select>
<span id="" class="selectboxit-container selectboxit-container" role="combobox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="">
<span id="" class="selectboxit accessory-option ng-pristine ng-valid selectboxit-enabled selectboxit-btn" name="" tabindex="0" unselectable="on" data-qa-quantity-value="">
<ul class="selectboxit-options selectboxit-list" tabindex="-1" role="listbox" aria-hidden="true" style="max-height: 217px; top: -217px; display: none;">
</span>
</div>
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Remove the `/` after `select` in your second example.

Comment: @DevTester85 Your comment `trying to automate the dropdown` is not clear to us. Can you consider updating the question about your exact steps you are trying to perform? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

Here is the working code block which navigates to "https://www.o2.co.uk/shop/smartwatches/samsung/gear-s2/#contractType=nonconnected", counts the number of entries in the `Quantity` DropDown, prints the output to the console and finally selects `Quantity` as **4** & prints to the console:

```
package demo;

import java.util.List;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Q44559302_dropdown_select {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        String innerhtml = null;
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\your_directory\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.o2.co.uk/shop/smartwatches/samsung/gear-s2/#contractType=nonconnected");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@id='chooseTariffForm']//div[@class='quantiy-picker-wrapper']/div/span")).click();
        List<WebElement> element_list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//form[@id='chooseTariffForm']//div[@class='quantiy-picker-wrapper']/div/span/ul/li/a"));
        System.out.println("Number of Elements : "+element_list.size());
        for (int i=0; i<element_list.size(); i++)
        {
            WebElement my_element = element_list.get(i);
            innerhtml = my_element.getText();

            if(innerhtml.contentEquals("4"))
            {
                my_element.click();
                break;
            }


        }
        System.out.println("Value selected from Dropdown is : "+innerhtml);

    }

}
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use select class because the page select box doesn't have select tag.

To select the option, first click on the select box and then click on list option which ever you want.

Following code will click on first option

```
        //click on dropdown
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@on-dimension-select = 'selectQuantityDimension']/*[@role='combobox']")).click();

        //click on first option 1
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@on-dimension-select = 'selectQuantityDimension']/*[@role='combobox']/ul/li[@data-val=1]/a")).click();
```

Comment: It does have `<select>` tag. Have a look at the html posted in the question.

Comment: But that is hidden, you can not use that, When I inspect, it is going to div tag.

Answer (score 0):

The drop down is Angular and the DOM you have pasted has Select Tag pointing to somewhere else in the webpage.

1. Click on the quantity drop down:

   ```
   driver.findElement(by.xpath("//div[@class='quantiy-picker-wrapper']//span[@class='selectboxit-container selectboxit-container']")).click();
   ```

Now the option from the drop down will be visible to the user.

2. Select a value from the dropdown:

   ```
   //am selecting quantity 4
   driver.findElement(by.xpath("//div[@class='quantiy-picker-wrapper']//span[@class='selectboxit-container selectboxit-container']//li[4]")).click();
   ```

Hope this helps you. Thanks.

Comment: cant i use select option at all ?  because if you see the html, there is select tag but its hidden

Comment: yes in this case we cant.., the quantity drop down in UI is not pointing to the select drop down but to angular drop down .., list